# style issues in display in IE8 vs IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-8, styles

I have a lot of issues right now for display in IE8, the pages are appropriately styled in IE9, 
I am attaching a sample screenshot of the page difference.
I have used a css-html based template skin called theme forest constellation admin template and I am not sure of its support for IE8

anyways I am using all kinds of styles some of which are
 ul, li elements, margins, auto width, display: block, inline, float: left... etc

I want to know how can I start fixing the display in IE8, do I have to fix each style manually or is there a list of know differences I can refer to between IE8 & 9 and then see if I have used any of those to fix.
The below diagram shows the difference, issues are
1) the grey bar below the date input
2) the chart div boxes in IE8 are shifted down to and little part of it is outside the box

[image: display difference between IE8 and IE9]

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to address IE8 compatibility issues as you discover them and whenever possible use libraries and frameworks that gauruntee IE8 support if this is a priority.

As far as general references for IE CSS/HTML bugs: http://jhop.me/ie8-bugs
And for a list of CSS compatibility by browser: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: That's very odd, they both work for me, and in multiple browsers.

Comment: Yes I had to provide IE 8 specific hacks in the stylesheets, especially the margin-bottom style was the cause and we set it to 0 for IE 8 and the differences are very few right now. Thanks for the links..

Answer (score 0):

The only real difference in IE8 vs IE9 (besides CSS3 support) is the default font, margin, and padding etc values. This is why it is critical to use a standard CSS Reset:
http://www.cssreset.com/

Eric Meyer's is a popular choice:
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

After the reset, you wont have to modify margin-bottom values for individual browsers.

Note: you may need to provide different defaults to get your site to look right, but afterwards, you will have a lot less headaches with cross-browser issues, assuming you only have to support IE8+.

Also, there are some minor differences between the native IE8 browser, and an IE9+ browser running in IE8 emulation mode, so you will need a native IE8 browser for testing.